# Hierarchical Kendo Grid - Angular and Popup Editor templates in the Detail Grid

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

Referring to the demo http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy

This is a Kendo Grid with hieracrchy.

Ive modified this so the demo uses angualar js.

Does anyone know how to use the popup editor in the detail grid and initialise a dropdown list using static items defined in the scope of the controller for the view that houses the parent grid?

It appears to me that the scope of the parent grid is not avaialable in the template of the detail popup editor.

I can successfully initialise a dropdown list using a popup editor in the main grid.

Please click here for piccie of setup...

[image]